# Orbits of a group action on a product

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions, permutation-cycles

I'm being asked to describe all different orbits of the action of $S_5$ on the product $[5]\times [5] \times [5]$ (where $[5]$ is a set of five elements with standard permutation action of $S_5$).

While I think I understand the notion of orbits of group actions, I'm a little lost on what the "product $[5]\times [5] \times [5]$" means based on the description in the parentheses; could somebody point me in the right direction? Sorry if this is a dumb question, and thanks in advance!

Comment: So each element of $[5]\times[5]\times[5]$ is a vector of three permutations of some 5-element base set. Basically, each element of the vector picks out some permutation of the five elements in the base set. Then you let the symmetric group act on such a vector element wise, I suppose.

Comment: So given some vector $\langle \alpha, \beta,\gamma \rangle$ the orbit of $S_5$ acting on this element will be the "coordinated" set of vectors that are being traversed by $\langle \sigma\alpha, \sigma\beta,\sigma\gamma \rangle$ as $\sigma$ runs through all permutations in $S_5$, right?

Comment: The first thing to realize is that the following elements of [5]x[5]x[5] lie in different orbits: (1,1,1) , (1,2,1), (1,2,3). Think about why, and then you can figure out all the orbits.

Comment: @String No, the notation $[5]$ does not refer to $S_5$, it refers to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The elements of $[5]\times[5]\times[5]$ are not vectors of permutations, they are vectors of numbers from $1$-$5$.

Comment: @Ned You could make that an answer.

Comment: Thank you everyone! This was incredibly helpful -- also I'm pretty new to StackExchange and have limited experience in LaTeX so sorry about the poorly formatted question (and thanks @Shaun for the edit!)

Comment: @runway44: Sorry about that and thank you for clarifying!